# Reuse results of column in another column

Tags: mysql, database, select

If I have the query

```
SELECT id,name,SUM(investments) as total_investments, SUM(investments)/10 as per_ten_investment
FROM table1
GROUP BY name
```

is there any way for me to use total_investments in the calculation of per_ten_investment? So instead of the above can I use

```
SELECT id,name,SUM(investments) as total_investments, total_investments/10 as per_ten_investment
FROM table1
GROUP BY name
```

The above results in an error Unknown column 'total_investments' in 'field list'

The issues I'm having are much more complicated but it boils down to this one roadblock.
Thanks All.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to use a subquery then you could just reference the summed field.  With that said, I don't see anything wrong with your query:

```
SELECT id, name, total_investments, total_investments/10 per_ten_investment
FROM (SELECT id, name, SUM(investments) as total_investments
    FROM table1
    GROUP BY name) t
```

Also, depending on your data, you may want to add the `id` field to the `group by`.  Mysql is more forgiving that others.

Comment: My first query works fine, my real problem is that I have a massive amount of logic in my real query that I don't want to repeat twice, I would prefer to do it once, get the result and then use that result in another column

Answer (score -1):

This should also work

```
SELECT id,name,SUM(investments) as total_investments, SUM(investments)/10 as per_ten_investment
FROM table1
GROUP BY name
```

Comment: no, it's not... the /10 is now done on the aggregate SUM(investments) not total_investments... read carefully...

Comment: Did you see the OPs first query?  `SUM(investments)/10 as per_ten_investment` -- looks like yours...

Comment: We did read the qustion, apperently you did not. @sgeddes I did

Comment: This is the same as my first query